# Is "dynamic" a data type in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have read that `dynamic` is a data type in Dart, but is it correct to call it a data type? it doesn't seems like a data type, it seems like it is a way to allow your variable to be of any data type.

Answer (score 7):

In Dart, `dynamic` is a type. It belongs in the type hierarchy and is related to other types by the subtype relation.

It's a "top" type, which means that every type is a subtype of `dynamic`. (Including itself, because the "subtype" relation is reflexive - every type is considered a subtype of itself, and the term "proper subtype" is used when only talking about subtypes that are not also supertypes.)

Being a top type, it means any value can be assigned to a variable of type `dynamic`. So can they to any other top type, which mainly means `Object?`.
The difference between the two is that:

- An expression with static type `dynamic` can be assigned to *any* type. That's obviously unsafe, so the runtime inserts a check, a so called "implicit downcast" which works just like doing `as TargetType`.
- You can call any member on an expression with static type `dynamic`. That's obviously unsafe, so the runtime will throw if the object doesn't have such a member.

That kind of runtime checked unsafe behavior (not static type-checked) is the reason the type is named `dynamic`. Using `dynamic` is a way to *turn off* the static type system. Use with extreme care.

Whether you can call `dynamic` a "data type" depends on what you mean by "data type". The Dart language specification doesn't use the term "data type" about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The specifications call it a type (https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-408/)

> The type dynamic denotes the unknown type. If no static type
> annotation has been provided the type system assumes the declaration
> has the unknown type

> Type dynamic has methods for every possible identifier and arity, with
> every possible combination of named parameters. These methods all have
> dynamic as their return type, and their formal parameters all have
> type dynamic. Type dynamic has properties for every possible
> identifier. These properties all have type dynamic